# Basic GTE and LTE Performance taking a long time to process - Java & MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm doing a query at my db using java:

```
   criteria.and(EVENT_YEAR_MONTH_DAY).gte(eventDateFrom).lte(eventDateTo);
```

create this query:

```
{ "eventYearMonthDay" : { "$gte" : 20220430, "$lte" : 20220530}}
```

My collection returns around `20000 documents` and takes like 7 seconds to execute. Yes, I need all the data at once, pagination will not work.

How can I improve the performance? Maybe I need to create an index? How should it be done to improve the performance?

Comment: Do you have index on that field? Is it 20 or 20k?

Comment: @Gibbs I don't have any index. I tried to create a basic unique index on Mongo Compass but didn't improve anything. How should it be done? Returns 20 thousand records

Comment: Are you sure it takes 7 seconds to execute the query or iterate all the documents?

Comment: Basically this like takes 7 seconds -> `List<Event> events = mongoTemplate.find(query, Event.class);` because it's done without pagination. So events.size is 20k

Comment: It depends on how much of data you transfer over the network. It's not only mongo query. Query execution will be quicker